# Js obj with key name defined by Object.keys

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, key, javascript-objects

```js
var c = {
'aa-bb': [{ a: 1, v: 2}],
'cc-xz': [{ c: 2}]
}
console.log(Object.keys(c))
```

I need to create an object, whose keys (the name) must be from Object.keys.

For each key name an object of type array must be defined as below.

Can you give me a hand?

result:

```js
const res = {
  'aa-bb': Array(number).fill(0),
  'cc-xz': Array(number).fill(0)
};
```

Comment: where's your 'number' coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var c = {
  'aa-bb': [{
    a: 1,
    v: 2
  }],
  'cc-xz': [{
    c: 2
  }]
}

const keys = Object.keys(c);
let res = {},
  number = 5;
keys.forEach(key => res[key] = Array(number).fill(0));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the keys, and create pairs of `[key, array]`, and convert back to an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const fn = (obj, arrLengh) =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(obj)
      .map(key => [key, Array(arrLengh).fill(0)])
  );

const c = {"aa-bb":[{"a":1,"v":2}],"cc-xz":[{"c":2}]};

const result = fn(c, 5);

console.log(result);
```